# Vue + Webpack - exclude .scss from build

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass

Is there a way with Webpack to exclude a specific `.scss` file from being compiled to css and included in the build?

I have tried adding the following to `vue.config.js`, but it does not work —

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rule('scss').exclude.add("/src/themes/themes.scss");
  }
  ..
```